# Good practices for designing monthly subscription system in database

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I'd like to know how to design a monthly subscription software system in a database.
These systems are broadly used all over internet, though I can't find lots of stuff about database design.

In my case, these elements (and maybe some others I forgot) have to be included:

- Client
- Plan (like 'basic'/'premium'). Each plan has a monthly price, and an amount of credits (for instance: basic plan provides 30 credits per month and premium plans unlimited credits).
- Credits are a virtual money that is spent within the application.
- Subscription/Unsubscriptions
- Payments (Note that the price actually paid could be different from the base price of the plan because of discount, etc.)
- ... ?

In addition of database design, there could be triggers that need to be set to do this (?).

**My pain points:**

- I can't see in a general manner what is the global design of this
- Which one should be a row in the DB: the month_susbscrition (ie 1 row per client per month) or the subscription itself (ie 1 row per client)?
- How would you handle the automatic renewal of the monthly subscription?
- How would you handle payments designing if you foresee to use services like Paypal to handle automatic monthly payments?

**Note**

I voluntarily don't expose my needs in details because that way, the debate can stay generic and can be more useful to other people.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I would suggest y u discuss the hows of automated payments with your provider, they may have guidelines for what they want you to do. But in general you could create a monthly job on the database that creates a list of who is to be charged on the monthly renewal date. Then the provider would tell you how to send that list to them.

Comment: I really like this guy post - but it has discount missing - do buy a coffee if possible https://axellarsson.com/blog/modeling-saas-subscriptions-in-postgres/

Comment: I waited for it for 9 years. You do buy me a coffee ;)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I would use this model

Your clients

```
Client
------
Client ID
Name
...
```

Your plans (you can define new plans when you want).
I add a Price_per_year if you want to propose a discount if the client buys 12 months in one shot (but it's only an idea).

```
Plan
------
Plan ID
Name
Credits_per_month
Price_per_month
(Price_per_year)
```

Your subscriptions

```
Subscriptions
------
Subscription ID
Client ID
Plan ID
Subscription_start_timestamp
Subscription_end_timestamp
```

Considering this model I would use 1 row per client per plan.

When a client subscribes to an offer like "Premium with 1st month free !", your database would look like this :

```
Client
------
ID: 1; LastName: Foo; ...

Plan
------
ID: 1; Name: Premium; Credits: -1 (unlimited); Price_per_month: 30
ID: 2; Name: Premium 1st month offer; Credits: -1; Price_per_month: 0

Subscription
------
ID: 1, Client ID: 1, Plan ID: 2, Start: 2014-05-07 08:00, End: 2014-06-06 07:59
ID: 1, Client ID: 1, Plan ID: 1, Start: 2014-06-07 08:00, End: 9999-12-06 07:59
```

When a client unsubscribe the 1st July, update the column end in your Subscription table with the month and the year only (because you have pre-set the day and the time).

```
Subscription
------
ID: 1, Client ID: 1, Plan ID: 2, Start: 2014-05-07 08:00, End: 2014-06-06 07:59
ID: 1, Client ID: 1, Plan ID: 1, Start: 2014-06-07 08:00, End: 2014-07-06 07:59
```

To know if a client is not unsubscribe, you could use this :

```
Select Count(client.*) From Client client
Inner Join Subscription sub On sub.client_id = client.id
Where DATE_TODAY Between sub.start And sub.end
```

Make sure that you can't have 2 subscriptions for a client at the same time.

This allow you to handle automatically the monthly subscription **in your app**, but not with your bank/paypal account.

But some banks offer you two services:
 - Unique debit
 - Periodic debit

The second one would allow you to handle the monthly subscription.

Comment: Regarding the year price, I'd put that as a different plan, a different option.

Comment: You're right. The year price can also be compute outside the DB. Like for example `Price_per_month * 12 * 0.9` but then the option should appear in the `subscription` table.

Comment: I wouldn't calculate the discount outside the DB, I'd put it as a different plan and keep a length of a plan in the DB. So one plan would be 1 year with a month price of 'standard_price*0.9' and have a length of 12(months) or keep it in days/weeks/whatever you prefer.

Comment: But then it's a different use case. Here, we need to have an unlimited timeframe. I think the problem with the actual schema is that you can't know if the user chose a monthly or a yearly subscription. In this case, I would use a different plan as you said, but with a category (yearly, monthly) instead of a length.

Comment: I would add something like total months to the plan and then you can use that to calculate the end date of the plan when you insert to the subscriptions table. This way you will know when a plan is ending and needs renewal so you can send reminders to renew. You could also have auto renewals until notified differently as well as plans with a set end date with this model..

Comment: @Chambeur How would you capture a free trial?

Comment: @Amanni You can look at the second row of the `Plan` table in my example. You can see that `Price_per_month` is equal to 0 so it's a bit like a Free Trial.

Comment: @Chambeur balass!

Comment: I will not use this design, will cause many issues. Please see another design i like better below

Comment: if you renew or change your subscription before the other ends.

Comment: This design doesn't appear to track how many credits are remaining for each subscription

Answer (score 20):

Looking at the accepted answer I would add another table where all the changes or updates of a subscription or plan would be stored for back reference. This way you have a clear log on when and what plans were selected for what period.

I would make sure the subscription table would contain the variables which tells you if it is active or not, and to what date it is payed for and any other possible data you would require in daily operations.

The extra table will make sure of you being able to recreate any subscription at any given time if needed.

Comment: Can you share the design of that table?

Comment: next time share design with tables; so it can be helpful

Answer (score 6):

I would use a relational table design and a relational database.

I would have a Client table.

```
Client
------
Client ID
Client Last Name
Client First name
...
```

I would have a Subscription table

```
Subscription
------------
Subscription ID
Client ID
Subscription Purchased Time stamp
Subscription Started Time stamp
Subscription Ends Time stamp
```

I would have a Purchase table

```
Purchase
--------
Purchase ID
Subscription ID
Payment method
...
```

Now to answer your questions.  You should ask just one question at a time.

> Which one should be a row in the DB: the month_subscription (ie 1 row per client per month) or the subscription itself (ie 1 row per client)?

One row per subscription per month.

> How would you handle the automatic renewal of the monthly subscription?

Netflix just debits my PayPal account every month.  You could do the same with PayPal or with a credit card.  If you accept credit cards, you're going to have to make an arrangement with your bank, a credit card processor, or PayPal.

> How would you handle payments designing if you foresee to use services like PayPal to handle automatic monthly payments?

Netflix just debits my PayPal account every month.  You could do the same.

Comment: purchased time and started time aren't the same?

Comment: if you renew or change your subscription before the other ends.

Comment: That's an interesting design I was thinking the same, but then I thought why not merge the two tables, subscriptions & purchase? I am using a NoSQL DB and would rather do a single fetch rather than two

Comment: With NoSQL DB is totally a different story, though, its suggest-able to use a consistent database design system for large scale applications.

Comment: so means that `client` table is 1 to 1 with `subscription` table?

Comment: @uberrebu I think is 1 to many (1 client has many subscriptions). Renewals are handled like new subscriptions. I guess upgrades/downgrades are handled in the same way